# Enterprise Architect source code generation - use association names instead of m_$LinkClass

Tags: code-generation, enterprise-architect

I am using Sparx EA to generate java code but I am bit strugling when I have an associaton between classes. Code gets generated in a format m_$LinkClass which means m_targetClass even though the association has name which I would like to use.

Thanks for advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target role of association needs to be specified. Then it works :-)

Comment: Will do but cannot do it right away. There is two day period required.